# how to append a variable to an HTML element stored as string using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have an empty controlgroup, which I want to populate with buttons. Can't get it to work.

This is the controlgroup:

```
var $wrap = '<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>';
```

This is the button:

```
var $btn = '<a href="#some" data-role="button">Click</a>'
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$wrap.append( $btn );
```

But it's not working.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think $wrap is just a string, so I cannot call *append* on it. If so, how do I do it correctly?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>');
var $btn = $('<a href="#some" data-role="button">Click</a>');
$wrap.append( $btn );
```

There's probably fifty ways to this, like:

```
var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>'),
    $btn = '<a href="#some" data-role="button">Click</a>';

$wrap.children().append( $btn );
```

or:

```
var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>'),
    $btn = '<a href="#some" data-role="button">Click</a>';

$('[data-role="controlgroup"]', $wrap).append( $btn );
```

Comment: `btn` can actually just be text.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Sure it can, added a few more ways to do this, and I can think of quite a few more using filters and different selectors?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have strings, you need a jquery object to call append:

```
var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, those are strings. You'll want to turn them into jQuery objects using `$`.

```
var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>');
var $btn = $('<a href="#some" data-role="button">Click</a>');
```

Now to append `$btn` into `$wrap`, you can go find the inner div (which is where you want to append the element) and use `.append`:

```
$wrap.find("div").append($btn);
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/42AXy/)

Answer (score 0):

I think $wrap is just a string, so I cannot call append on it.

Yes.

You could try:

```
var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"><div data-role="controlgroup"></div></div>');
var $btn = '<a href="#some" data-role="button">Click</a>';
$wrap.append( $btn );
```